# Существует ли аналог python-config для Windows?

Tags: python, c, windows, компиляция, cython

Для компиляции кода на C, созданного с помощью Cython, на линукс я использую `python3-config`:

```
gcc `python3-config --cflags --ldflags` -fPIC -shared -o module.so module.c
```

Есть ли какой-то аналог этой программы в Windows?

Comment: Использовать для сборки Build Tools for Visual Studio 2015 C++

Comment: @Александр , на винде как раз использую Build Tools, только вот не знаю как все пути указать правильно...

Comment: Если у вас как в примере только module.c то не чего там указывать и не надо.

Comment: Вот здесь гляньте простой пример https://qna.habr.com/q/720065#answer_1541153

Comment: @Александр спасибо. Указывать надо, т. к. там используется `Python.h`. Но я всё это делал вручную (запускал `python -m cython -3 module.py && <команда компиляции из вопроса>`). Использование `setup` всё упрощает, приму ответ, если опубликуете :)

Comment: Вообще я я если честно до сих пор не могу переварить то что сделали создатели  Cython.

Comment: До того всё просто.

Comment: То есть как они это сделали)